# How to fix coordinated omission problem in locust?

Tags: python, performance, load-testing, locust

I am running locust in distributed mode for testing my backend service. I have observed one pattern that after every fix interval, I can see some dips in number of requests made to the backend service.

As far as I know, this is known as coordinated omission problem. Because of this I am getting incorrect rps value at the end of test run.

Please see the graph I am attaching with this question.

I am interested in knowing different ways to solve this issue in locust.

[image]